# Adding class tag to child-elements by using blockstyle for parent (Typo3 6.2.2)

Tags: typo3, typoscript, rte

is it possible to tell the RTE parser to modify the class-attribute of all direct child-elements, when a defined blockstyle is added to the parent-element?

## Edit 1

If the RTE content is something like this

```
<ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

and I add "my-custom-class" to the `ul`-element via blockstyle defined in TS.

```
<ul class="my-custom-class">
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

the RTE should automatically add "my-custom-sub-class" to all the `li`-elements

```
<ul class="my-custom-class">
   <li class="my-custom-sub-class">Item 1</li>
   <li class="my-custom-sub-class">Item 2</li>
   <li class="my-custom-sub-class">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

## Edit 2 - Workaround

Although it is not be possible with the RTE, you can still use JavaScript to achieve the result dynamically.

```
// jQuery -> https://jsfiddle.net/du6r7ow1/1/
$('ul.my-custom-class > li').addClass('my-custom-sub-class');

// MooTools -> https://jsfiddle.net/u53516cu/
$$('ul.my-custom-class > li').addClass('my-custom-sub-class');
```

Comment: we are talking about an RTE in a CMS (like tinyMCE in WordPress) right? if so, it's just too specific usage. see below for targeting specific elements with CSS instead.

Answer (score 0):

can you use this instead?

`.parent > children` will target ONLY direct descendants (specifically divs id=1 and id=2)

```
.parent > div {
    border:1px dashed red;
}

<div class="parent">
     <div id="1">this div will get targeted
        <div>this div won't get targeted</div>
        <p>jabberwocky</p>
    </div>
    <div id="2">this div will get targeted
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

would put a dashed red border around ONLY the two inner divs.

in other words, instead of trying to get an RTE editor to dynamically assign a class (requiring programming too particular for widespread use), you could just target the elements more specifically using CSS.

check out: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

you can use jQuery similarly: `jQuery('.parent > div').html()` for example

**EDIT** after seeing your edit to your post

```
ul.my-custom-class {
    /* definitions for the ul */
}
ul.my-custom-class > li {
    /* definitions for only the directly descended lis */
}

<ul class="my-custom-class">
   <li>Item 1</li>
       <ul>
           <li>will NOT be affected</li>
           <li>will NOT be affected</li>
       </ul>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

personally, i try very hard to avoid relying on being able to add classes to elements, and rely, instead, on the specific targeting capability of modern CSS

Comment: Just using css this would be the easiest way. But I thought I could use the RTE-blockstyles to implement the typical bootstrap List-Group-Feature.

Comment: right, but to automatically add a class to all direct children would require a lot of programming that would go unused by many people i would imagine. it is also asking the RTE to a bit of a mind reader, or at least require an elaborate interface to configure the RTE to automatically assign classes -- and how well would it manage that when many of them can't handle simpler things? and what about removing those classes? sadly, i think what you're asking is a bit of a dream destined to become a nightmare...

Comment: Well, then it would be better to define two different blockstyles, one for the `ul`- and another for the `li`-elements.

Comment: everything i googled for Typo RTE addresses adding multiple classes to the same element but not automatically adding classes to descendent elements. again, i prefer using the CSS to grab on to specifically what i need. it keeps the resulting HTML smaller and makes it easier for me to read too.